# Detect client using site in mobile

Tags: php, responsive-design

Can we detect client's **Operating System** using PHP, That it is Mobile, Android or Windows to display site's design responsive.

I have used,

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
     /*
         Detected PC.
     */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
     /*
         Detected Mobile or PC.
     */
}
```

But I don't want to write both CSS in same page and wanted to load them with PHP

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $is_pc = ???; //Don't know what to write.
    if ($is_pc) {
       echo '<link href="pc.css" rel="stylesheet">';
    } else {
       echo '<link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet">';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to know the OS - just the size of the window/viewport that is being used. Your media queries can then handle the variations needed. To see the different resolutions head on over to http://mobiphonespec.com/cellphone-screen-resolution-by-size.php

Comment: Just: no. What you're trying to do is *user agent sniffing*, which is precisely contrary to *responsive design*. In responsive design you include all the CSS to make it work in any size, and let the browser figure it out. Sniffing the agent on the server and returning different content based on that takes power away from the browser to "figure it out itself" and causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: CSS size is pretty small, esspecially once gzipped and your site won't actually be responsive if you try to select by mobile (what happens if someone rotates their phone). Is there a reason other than bandwidth you don't want to send both?

Comment: `I don't want to write both CSS in same page` put them in two and send them both if it really mean for you to have two file. If the size matter (witch is stupid if you look at an image one), compress your CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad practice and the main, but far from only one, is :

If you choose witch CSS to load server side, you'll not be able to handle the switch on tablet between vertical and horizontal mode (hz = desktop view; vt = mobile one), as you'll not have a reload of the page.

This is why you should load both media query in your CSS at the same time.

---

If you want to make the same behaviour, use this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="pc.css" />
```

Answer (score -2):

I got my answer.

After a long research on `HTTP_USER_AGENT`.

I got this:

**PHP**

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(!preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))) {
    echo '<link href="pc.css" rel="stylesheet">';
    } else {
    echo '<link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet">';
    }
?>
```

Comment: **No, just no please**. This is against Google good practice, Will shut your website at the bottom of the Google result; Will fail for any Anonymous  User Agent; Same for new UA that you don't know; Don't handle resizing of windows; Same for switch between Horizontal and Vertical on tablet; and will probably kill baby unicorn...

Answer (score -2):

My recommendation is with the client side in javascript.
The first need is a method for the detection of the client **window.mobileAndTabletcheck()**

```
window.mobileAndTabletcheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;}
```

Next, You need say, ajax for reading styles, **loadCSS(file,CallBack)**

```
function loadCSS(file,CallBack){
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var ts = "?"+new Date().getTime();// use timestamp for prevent caching
xmlhttp.open('GET', file+ts,true);
xmlhttp.onload=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        var style=document.createElement("style");
        style.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.head.appendChild(style);
        CallBack();
    };
};
xmlhttp.send();};
```

and finally You got

```
if(window.mobileAndTabletcheck()){
loadCSS("mobile.css",function(){console.log('loaded mobile');});}else{
loadCSS("pc.css",function(){console.log('loaded pc');});}
```

In the **head** tag you will have loaded styles.

Comment: Or you could do the same with a `media` query attribute in the `style` tag and let the browser figure out which stylesheet it needs...!?

Comment: Straight on, but this gives you more control because you now have the function Calback

Comment: @DusanKrstic it just give you a big latency in the display of the style... And use the same User Agent based thing that the OP use with PHP : we said it's a bad practice and you should use the windows weight with media query, not the UA.